# How do i write a function to randomly select a name from an array without selecting the last element

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, arraylist

I am writing a function to randomly select an item from an array to insert into an output that says " "NAME SELECTED AT RANDOM" is paying for lunch today!.
everything looks good from my end but I do not understand why it is not running.
Udemy is also not accepting the solutions provided
[ScreenShot from Udemy js editor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ckhck.png)

```
var names = ["Hameed", "David", "Maleek", "Ola"];

function whosPaying(names){
    var output;
    var arr_length = names.length;
    var index = Math.floor(Math.random() * (arr_length-1));
    output = names[index] + " is going to pay for lunch today!";
     
    return output;
}
```

Comment: You're not calling the function

Comment: maybe `console.log(whosPaying(names))`?

Comment: He's also never going to get other index but 0 because the usual `Math.random` returns a value in [0-1]!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here I recreated the legacy Math.random function to support in between range and then fixed the range[0, arr_length-1] and this should be working as a charm for your case.

`Clarification: He's also never going to get other index but 0 because the usual` Math.random`returns a value in [0-1]! That's why I had to recreate the`Math.random `method for him and then just fix the new range to [0-arr_length-1]. And that guarantees him to get each time a random index in the correct range.`

Also you will need to call your function in order to get the results!

```js
(function(){
  const originalMathRandom = Math.random;
  Math.random = function(min=0, max=1) {
    return originalMathRandom() * (max - min) + min;
  }
}());

var names = ["Hameed", "David", "Maleek", "Ola"];

function whosPaying(names){
    var output;
    var arr_length = names.length;
    var index = Math.floor(Math.random(0, arr_length-1));
    output = names[index] + " is going to pay for lunch today!";
     
    return output;
}

console.log( whosPaying(names) );
```

Comment: This works! but i am so confused! the first function declaration looks strange to me

Comment: I have just optimized the `Math.random` method, by allowing it to have parameters since the original method doesn't allow us to define the needed range!
So basicaly I took the original method and store it in another variable or scope or whatever you want to call it, and then I had to reprovide the same prototype method with new function that allows 2 parameters (min, max), and then I used the original method to create a random number between 0-1 and multiplied the result by (max - min) then add the `min` and that will give you a random number between the needed range [min-max] not [0-1].

Comment: @Abdulhameed If you are talking about the `(function(){}())` declaration it's just a normal function that calls itself once the script gets executed, and gives you a free scope since we are writing our variables on a separated block `{...}`.

Answer (score 0):

This works!

```
var names = ["Hameed", "David", "Maleek", "Ola"];


function whosPaying(names){

    var arr_length = names.length;
    var posInArray = Math.floor(Math.random() * arr_length );
    var randomPerson = names[posInArray];
    var output = randomPerson + " is going to buy lunch today!";

    return output
    
}

whosPaying(names);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function whosPaying(names) {
    
    var Numberofpeople= names.length;
    var randompersonposition = Math.floor(Math.random() * Numberofpeople);
    var randomperson = names[randompersonposition];
    
    return randomperson + " is going to buy lunch today!";
    
}
```

Comment: Can you add some explanatory text, which shows how this answer differs *significantly*  from [this earlier answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68011027/10871073)?

Answer (score 0):

var names = ["David", "Maleek", "Ola"];

```js
var names = ["David", "Maleek", "Ola"];

function whosPaying(names){
    var output;
    var randomPeople = names.length;
    var randomPerson = Math.floor(Math.random(1, randomPeople + 1));
    output = names[randomPerson] + " is going to pay for lunch today!";
     
    return output;
}
```

Comment: It's important to not just post code, but to also include a description of what the code does and why you are suggesting it. This helps others understand the context and purpose of the code, and makes it more useful for others who may be reading the question or answer.